# Managing data-flow between Controller Hiearchy

Tags: angularjs

There is a part of my application that has information shared between 3 separate pages.  I have an abstract "Order" controller that is instantiated whenever its children are instantiated. The children are "Overview", "Alerts", and "Accounts". So my view/controller hierarchy looks like

```
                                   Order
                                   / |  \
                                  /  |   \
                                 /   |    \
                                /    |     \
                               /     |      \
                          Overview  Alerts  Accounts
```

At the top of all 3 of these pages I am displaying some "Order"-level information like a Customer name, therefore I make my API call in the "Order" controller so that it may be used on any of the pages.  The thing is I want to keep my convention of sticking all my my API data inside of a "model" object like `$scope.model`.  I tried to use `angular.extend` in my "Overview" controller to extend this controller's `$scope.model` with the `$scope.model` that exists in "Order" controller, the problem is that `angular.extend` executes before the API call gets returned so I am basically just extending a blank object that never actually gets filled with the API data.

My solution was to use Angular Events to trigger from the Parent to the Child in order to extend the object after the API call is done.  My code looks like this:

**Order Controller**

```
$scope.model = new OrderModel();

    API.Backups.getBackupService({ id: $stateParams.orderId }, function (data) {
        $scope.model.BackupService.data = data.result;
        $scope.$broadcast('parentDataReceived', $scope.model.BackupService.data);
    });
```

**Overview Controller**

```
$scope.model = new OverviewModel();

    $scope.$on('parentDataReceived', function (event, data) {
        angular.extend($scope.model.BackupService.data, data);
    });
```

This works well, but I do not think it is the best solution.  Has this been solved before in a more elegant way or is my way alright?

---

So would a more correct solution be

```
app.factory('OrderService', function() {
  var OrderService = {};
  var order = {};

  OrderService.getOrder = function(id) { //send API call to get order information via OrderID }
  OrderService.updateOrder = function(order) { //send API to PUT the new order information to the server }
  OrderService.Current = order;

  return OrderService;
});
```

Comment: Your `Order` object should definitely be a service. could you setup a small demo so I can help you more efficiently?

Comment: I always hear that things should be Services but I just don't get how that can be tied in my the controller logic. I feel like we would need to do this all over the application

Comment: No logic should be placed in controller. They need to be as lean as possible. Their goal is to be the glue between your model and the view. Your model should be within services

Comment: No logic in the controller? I thought that is the whole point of a controller. Could you direct me to an example that uses Services as a model then?

Comment: http://www.stackdriver.com/managing-missing-model-angular/  I cannot do more now, I am on my smartphone. Rgds

Comment: Should I do something like http://www.webdeveasy.com/angularjs-data-model/

Comment: I do like the idea. Let me know if you need help inplementing it.

Comment: Did you achieved what you wanted using the service pattern?

Comment: I am going to try converting my current models to service models right now. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You're getting things the wrong way round. You don't need to make your REST call from your controller and then push the data to your model when the data is received (effectively pushing data from your controller out to the service).

Rather, you bind your view to a service's data via the controller's $scope, and let the data flow from the service through your controller's $scope and out into your view.

To do this, create an Orders service, and then assign a property on your Controller's $scope (e.g. $scope.model.order) to this Orders service's currentOrder property. Then, when the data is received, just assign it to the currentOrder property in the Orders service.

Because your Controller's $scope.model.order property references (i.e. 'is bound to') the same object as Orders.currentOrder, $scope.model.order will update immediately as well, as will the view (i.e. the HTML)

So in your example, you'd have something like this:

### Controller

```
angular.module('OrderApp', [])
.controller('OrderCtrl', ['$scope', 'Orders', function($scope, Orders){

    // $scope.model glues the values in your actual model (Orders service) to the
    // view defined in your HTML template.
    $scope.model = {};

    // Assign $scope.model.order to OrderService.currentOrder. Because 
    // $scope.model.order and Orders.currentOrder both reference the same 
    // object, whenever Orders.currentOrder changes, $scope.model.order 
    // will change as well.  
    //
    // Note that in your view, {{model.order}} will also automatically
    // update.
    $scope.model.order = OrderService.getCurrentOrder();

    // Assume in your view you have a button wired up to getOrder() 
    // (e.g. ng-click=getOrder() ). Then you can display a message 
    // depending on whether the data has been successfully retrieved 
    // or not, like so:
    $scope.getOrder() = function(){

        // Call Orders' getOrder(). This will populate 
        // Orders.currentOrder; the change in currentOrder will
        // instantly be reflected in $scope.model.order as they both 
        // reference the same object, so you don't need to worry about 
        // reassigning $scope.model.order to the new object referenced 
        // by Orders.currentOrder.
        Orders.getOrder().then(function(){
            $scope.infoMsg = "Order received ok";
        },
        function(){
            $scope.errorMsg = "Error receiving order";
        });

})
```

### Orders Service

```
// OrderService acts as your model
.factory('OrderService', ['API', function(API){

    var currentOrder = {};

    // These are the public functions that your Controller 
    // (and other services) can use
    var service = {
        getOrder: getOrder,
        getCurrentOrder: getCurrentOrder,
        updateOrder: updateOrder
    }

    return service;

    /////////////

    function getOrder(){
        // Return $http's promise to your Controller
        return API.getBackupServiceData().then(function(data){
            // When the data is retrieved, currentOrder is populated.
            // The change in currentOrder will automatically be 
            // reflected in your Controller's $scope.model.order as 
            // they both reference the same object
            currentOrder = data;
        });
    }

    function getCurrentOrder(){
        return currentOrder;
    }
})
```

### Separate API service

```
.factory('API', ['$http', function($http){

    var service = {
        getBackupServiceData: getBackupServiceData;
    };

    return service;

    ////////////

    function getBackupServiceData(){
        // Return $http's promise
        return $http.get({ id: $stateParams.orderId }, function (data) {
            // transform data if needed
            return data;
        },
        function(response){
            // handle error
        }
    });

}])
```

Note that you'll frequently read that the controller should be the 'glue' between your model and view, but it's not always obvious what that means in Angular-land.

Put simply, your controller should only contain assignments to the $scope. If you have a function in the controller that contains business logic, or which otherwise acts on or transforms data that's ultimately assigned to the $scope, put that function in a service.